# Communication between two microservices deployed in docker container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, microservices

Two microservices are deployed on AWS inside a container.I have a scenario where my microservice-A have to communicate with microservice-B. But When i tried with http://localhost:8082/url then it didn't work. Unfortunately i had to use the public url of my microservices. Due to the use of public url performance is getting slow.

Can anyone please help me ,so that microservices can be able to communicate on localhost inside docker container.

Comment: Please provide `dockerfile` and `docker run` command of both the micro-services.

Comment: How do you deploy the microservices in AWS? Which AWS servise do you use?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a docker network for this. I have achieved this using docker-compose. In the following example I have defined a network back-tier and both the services belong to it. After this your application can access your DB with its service name http://database:27017.

```
version: '3'

    networks:
      back-tier:

    services:
      database:
        build: ./Database
        networks:
          - back-tier
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
      backend:
        build: ./Backend
        networks:
          - back-tier
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
          - database
```

Comment: [Docker Compose provides a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) so you don't need any of the `networks:` blocks in this answer.